# What do you call a space on a street that can be leased to a shop?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a space on a street that can be leased to a shop? I was thinking of "block" but I don't think it's quite right. Here are some example sentences.

After the construction of the street is finished, the ____ will be leased to shops.

There is a big H&M on that street which takes up three ____. Their address is 48-50 New Street.

Comment: Your example of 48-50 New Street is a very British English way of specifying street addresses.  Are you looking for a particularly British expression for this?

Comment: The term I've seen used for this is "storefront"--but I don't know enough about commercial real estate to give that as a definite Answer.

Comment: The street-facing part of a shop is know as the *frontage*. Newly built shops are generally divided into *units*. Larger commercial property sizes are specified by total floor space. In the UK (and probably the USA), these values will be in feet and square feet.

Comment: "Commercial spaces".

Comment: Agree with StonyB, Also “retail spaces” “retail units”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unit** could work:

> u·nit  ˈyo͞onət
> an individual thing or person regarded as single and complete but which can also form an individual component of a larger or more complex whole.
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unit)</sub>

Unit is commonly used in reference to empty apartments, and shops.  Generally only used when it is part of a greater whole structurally.  i.e. referring to a house as a unit would be inappropriate because a house is generally a free standing structure.

Comment: Nice answer, but I would suggest you leave out the "noun noun unit..." thing. Please tell us where you found the definition, ideally with a link.

Answer (score 0):

What about a ***stall***, a ***lot***, or a ***booth***?

Comment: This is a useful suggestion, but it ought to have been made as a comment.

Comment: @Mick Oh I see. Sorry for the newb mistake and thanks for the advice!

Comment: A stall reminds me of something like at Pike Place Market, not a building